# Mathematical operations with Boolean values in php

Tags: php

I was experimenting with some `Boolean` values and just out of curiosity I tried this:

```
$_r = TRUE + FALSE;
if ($_r) ? print 'TRUE' : print 'FALSE'; // Prints TRUE
```

and I found that returns `TRUE`, even the subtraction (no matter the order) `TRUE - FALSE` returns `TRUE`.
Is that possible, to add, multiply, divide or subtract `Boolean` values ?

Comment: Simple: PHP type juggling

Comment: If you're here because of a brain fart like me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553004/boolean-assignment-operators-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick quote from the PHP documentation about [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

> An example of PHP's automatic type conversion is the addition operator '+'. If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as integers, and the result will also be an integer. Note that this does not change the types of the operands themselves; the only change is in how the operands are evaluated and what the type of the expression itself is.

Let's apply this to your code `$_r = TRUE + FALSE;`: since none of the operands (`TRUE` and `FALSE`) is float, they are converted to integer (`TRUE` == `1`, `FALSE` == `0`) and the addition becomes `1+0`. The result (integer `1`) is stored in variable `$_r`.

On the next statement (`if ($_r) print 'TRUE'; else print 'FALSE';`), the [`if` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) takes the expression inside the parentheses and evaluates its boolean value. Any integer number different than zero is `TRUE`, zero is `FALSE`. The value of `$_r` is `1` and converted to boolean it becomes `TRUE`. Consequently, the code prints `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that this is acceptable by [PHP](http://php.net/) because it treats `TRUE` and `FALSE` values as `1` and `0`respectively and that the common mathematical operations of the addition, subtraction, division and multiplication are totally allowed with `Boolean` values, here is the proof:

```
$_r = FALSE * TRUE; // (0 * 1)
if ($_r) ? print 'TRUE' : print 'FALSE'; // prints FALSE

$_r = FALSE / TRUE; // (0 / 1)
if ($_r) ? print 'TRUE' : print 'FALSE'; // prints FALSE

$_r = TRUE / FALSE; // (1 / 0)
if ($_r) ? print 'TRUE' : print 'FALSE'; // prints Warning: **Division by zero**
```

Comment: Don't forget about Elvis.. `print $_r?'TRUE':'FALSE';`

Comment: I have nothing to do with the downvotes. I was just pointing out that you could use the alternative syntax using what's called the elvis operator, or ternary operators. No harm intended https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: I didn't know that the [shorthand if/else](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) was also called [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator), nice! As for the downvote was a question like: "what's wrong with my answer ?" not specific to you.